# A usage of the word candidature

Tags: single-word-requests

Is it correct to say:
thank you for the invitation to the interview and for your interest in my candidature?

Comment: If it’s just a question of grammar, it’s fine as it is. Whether it is “correct” is a much broader matter that takes into consideration intent, clarity, and even custom and local lingo.

Comment: I would suggest removing “the”, since there wouldn’t have been an interview if they didn’t invite you. Also, do you really want to thank them for their interest in you being a candidate? That’s a strange thing to thank them for. Maybe instead you could thank them for considering you. “Thank you for the invitation to interview, and considering me for the position.” But those two things are pretty much the same, so it might be better just to say “Thank you for the invitation to interview.”

Answer (score 3):

[*Candidature*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidature) is grammatical, but according to Merriam-Webster it is "chiefly British"—which is fine, if regionalism is not a concern.

However, a more universal, and commonly used, version of the word is [**candidacy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidacy):

> : the state of being a candidate
> // he is expected to announce his *candidacy*
> // He withdrew his *candidacy* after the scandal damaged his reputation.

---

According to Google Ngram Viewer, *candidacy* is currently more common than *candidature*, even in the UK:

[image: candidacy versus candidature in the UK]

Comment: I'm not supposed to say, "Good answer."